# Installation pop-up perior to the download . how?

Tags: android

I wanna implement a download-and-install mechanism. I have a source link where my app gonna download from, an apk file.

Ive managed to do it, but i payed attention to the fact, that it first download then when it finish downloading it pop up an installation window and then install.

now this this can interrupt the user, if he is in the middle of conversation or some anothe opeartion, and all of a sudden the installtaion pop-up window, coming up after download successful.

In the market it works in a diffrent way: first it's up an installation window, and then downloading, and installing (in the background)

how can i achive it also the same way as the downloading mechanism of the market?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so because `PackageManager` is not available for apps.

Follow [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg05512.html) thread, they say which is the best way to solve your issue.

Comment: I cant find an answer for my question in this thread..
i just want to stimulate the installation flow as it's in google market..

Comment: Yes, not possible, you will definitely get the confirmaion dialog again when you start to install the apk after the download.

Comment: Little bit annoying, wonder how it could be 'fixed' in other ways.